# Rotations have degree $1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, rotations

In p.233 of Hatcher's ***Algebraic Topology***, there is a statement that a rotation of a sphere $S^n$ has degree, homotopic to the identity. I have some questions about these.

1. How do we define a rotation in $\Bbb R^n$?
2. In the above definition, how can we show that it is homotopic to the identity?

Comment: I think of rotations as members of the special orthogonal group. They're linear isometries that aren't reflections and that means they're represented well by orthogonal matrices of deteriminant one, ie the special orthogonal group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. As @CyclotomicField said, I'll interpret a rotation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be an element of $\text{SO}(n)$, i.e. an orientation-preserving Euclidean isometry fixing the origin. Equivalently, they are $n\times n$ real matrices $R$ with $\det R = 1$ and $R R^T = 1$.
2. There is a nice factorization of a rotation $A \in \text{SO}(n)$ into $A = QRQ^T$, where

   - $Q$ is orthogonal,
   - $R$ is block-diagonal, with blocks being $2 \times 2$ rotation matrices $R_{\theta}$, or possibly a 1 if $n$ is odd.

   See Corollary 0.2 in [this](https://www.math.tamu.edu/~rojas/son.pdf) explanation by J. Maurice Rojas, for example. This factorization recovers the familiar result that a 3-D rotation is described uniquely by an axis and an angle of rotation about that axis.

   Now, to deform $R$ to the identity, simply "dial down" the parameters $\theta_i$ in the block decomposition of $R$ until each $\theta_i = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define an $n$-dimensional axis and a rotation angle $0 \leq \theta < 2 \pi$ around it.
2. We can always continuously apply a rotation to an $n$-sphere to bring it back to its original orientation (identity).  That defines the homotopy.